# JQuery posting content with UTF8 characters not working

Tags: jquery, utf-8

I have a JQuery script posting the contents of a form field to a simple servlet. When I put Chinese characters (in utf8) in the form field and post using JQuery .ajax() method the server sees the characters as question marks (欢迎进入智慧的十年 is seen as ??????????? on the server).

`$.ajax({ 
  url: '/url-on-server', 
  type: 'POST',
  data: 'action=SEND&'+ $('#text-field').val()),
  success: function(){},
  dataType: 'json'
}`

I have inspected the request with FIREBUG and Liveheaders and they look right...

`Content-Type    text/plain; charset=UTF-8`

I believe it's not a server side thing b/c when I change the html form to post without the JQuery script it works great. I can see the Chinese characters on the server side without changing anything on that side.

Another clue..

When i post the form using JQuery $.ajax() method.  This is what the request looks like in LiveHeaders...

`action=SEND&msg=%E6%AC%A2%E8%BF%8E%E8%BF%9B%E5%85%A5%E6%99%BA%E6%85%A7%E7%9A%84%E5%8D%81%E5%B9%B4`

However when I post the form the traditional web1.0 way, this is what I see in live headers.

`action=SEND&msg=%26%2327426%3B%26%2336814%3B%26%2336827%3B%26%2320837%3B%26%2326234%3B%26%2324935%3B%26%2330340%3B%26%2321313%3B%26%2324180%3B`

As you can see it seems to be encoding the parameters in a different way but I haven't been able to Google an explanation or a way to fix this.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The first:

```
action=SEND&msg=%E6%AC%A2%E8%BF%8E%E8%BF%9B%E5%85%A5%E6%99%BA%E6%85%A7%E7%9A%84%E5%8D%81%E5%B9%B4
```

...is the URL-escaped form for the string:

```
action=SEND&msg=欢迎进入智慧的十年
```

The second:

```
action=SEND&msg=%26%2327426%3B%26%2336814%3B%26%2336827%3B%26%2320837%3B%26%2326234%3B%26%2324935%3B%26%2330340%3B%26%2321313%3B%26%2324180%3B
```

...is the URL-escaped form for the UTF-8 string:

```
action=SEND&msg=&#27426;&#36814;&#36827;&#20837;&#26234;&#24935;&#30340;&#21313;&#24180;
```

Those HTML entities, I presume (I haven't checked) are your Asian characters. However, I did not think it was valid to send HTML entities in x-www-form-urlencoded things - that the character itself should be used, so I'm surprised you're seeing that. In a quick test, submitting your Asian string to http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/ (first POST form I could find), I get the example, not the second one. Are you sure the second is what is being transmitted? (I'd check with Wireshark) What browser, how is the form constructed, etc.?